# Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. Given $a>0$, prove that there exists some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $a_n>0$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Note.** $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in **R**.

I need to prove the claim in the title. The following is what I have got so far:

Suppose for contradiction that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_n\leq 0.$ Let $a$ be greater than $0$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, it follows that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that given $\epsilon>0$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0.$ Since $a>0,$ $a+\epsilon>0$. Therefore, we have $-\epsilon<a-\epsilon<a_n\leq 0<\epsilon<a+\epsilon.$
In particular, $-\epsilon<a_n<\epsilon$.

**Note.** I am aware of the following theorems:

1. All convergent sequences in **R** is bounded.
2. The limit of a sequence in **R** is unique.

Comment: Otherwise, you can find a subsequence $\{b_n\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ such that $b_n\le 0$ for each $n$. The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ has to be $a>0$, which is clearly a contardiction.

Comment: For the contradiction, you assume that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n_0 \ge n$ such that $a_n \le 0$.

Comment: No!!! It is not true that there exists $n_0$ such that given $\epsilon>0$, [etc]. What's tur is that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :** Apply the definition of the convergence with $$\varepsilon = \frac{a}{2} > 0$$

Comment: This is the kind of questions where the first thought should be “this must have been asked and aswered before”!

Comment: @MartinR Hmm yes sorry... I am not very good at searching for duplicates. Bill Dubuque will be angry.